# Yet another subquery issue

Tags: sql-server, subquery

Hello from an absolute beginner in SQL!

I have a field I want to populate based on another table. For this I have written this query, which fails with: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

oK, here goes:

```
Update kre.CustomerOrderLineCopy 
SET    DepNo = (SELECT customerordercopy.DepNo 
                          FROM   kre.CustomerOrderCopy , kre.CustomerOrderLineCopy
                          WHERE  CustomerOrderLineCopy.OrderCopyNo =kre.CustomerOrderCopy.OrderCopyNo) 
WHERE CustomerOrderLineCopy.OrderCopyNo = (SELECT  CustomerOrderCopy.OrderCopyNo 
                             FROM   kre.CustomerOrderCopy, kre.CustomerOrderLineCopy
                             WHERE kre.CustomerOrderLineCopy.OrderCopyNo = kre.CustomerOrderCopy.OrderCopyNo)
```

What I'm trying to do is to change DepNo in CustomerOrderLineCopy, with the value in DepNo in CustomerOrderCopy - based on the same OrderCopyNo in both tables.

I'm open for all suggestion.

Thanks,
ohalvors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just join the tables together the update is easier:

```
UPDATE A SET A.DepNo = B.DepNo
FROM kre.CustomerOrderLineCopy A
INNER JOIN kre.CustomerOrderCopy B ON A.OrderCopyNo = B.OrderCopyNo
```

Comment: Thank you! I used your suggestion and did get what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that at least one of your sub queries return more than one value. Think about this:

tablePerson(name, age)

Adam, 11

Eva, 11

Sven 22

```
    update tablePerson
    set name = (select name from tablePerson where age = 11)
    where name = 'Sven'
```

Which is equivalent to: set Sven's name to Adam **and** Eva. Which is not possible.

If you want to use sub queries, either make sure your sub queries can only return one value or force one value by using:

```
select top 1 xxx from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be enough to quieten it down:

```
Update kre.CustomerOrderLineCopy 
SET    DepNo = (SELECT customerordercopy.DepNo 
                          FROM   kre.CustomerOrderCopy --, kre.CustomerOrderLineCopy
                          WHERE  CustomerOrderLineCopy.OrderCopyNo =kre.CustomerOrderCopy.OrderCopyNo) 
WHERE CustomerOrderLineCopy.OrderCopyNo = (SELECT  CustomerOrderCopy.OrderCopyNo 
                             FROM   kre.CustomerOrderCopy --, kre.CustomerOrderLineCopy
                             WHERE kre.CustomerOrderLineCopy.OrderCopyNo = kre.CustomerOrderCopy.OrderCopyNo)
```

(Where I've commented out `kre.CustomerOrderLineCopy` in the subqueries) That is, you were *hopefully* trying to correlate these subqueries with the outer table - not introduce another instance of `kre.CustomerOrderLineCopy`.

If you still get an error, then you still have multiple rows in `kre.CustomerOrderCopy` which have the same `OrderCopyNo`. If that's so, you need to give us (and SQL Server) the rules that you want to apply for how to select which row you want to use.

The danger of switching to the `FROM ... JOIN` form shown in @Avitus's answer is that it will no longer report if there are multiple matching rows - it will just silently pick one of them - which one is never made clear.

---

Now I look at the query again, I'm not sure it even needs a `WHERE` clause now. I think this is the same:

```
Update kre.CustomerOrderLineCopy 
SET    DepNo = (
   SELECT customerordercopy.DepNo 
   FROM   kre.CustomerOrderCopy
   WHERE  CustomerOrderLineCopy.OrderCopyNo = kre.CustomerOrderCopy.OrderCopyNo)
```

Comment: Thanks for this one - although it gave the same error. I had already tried it the suggested way. I ended up using Avitus' answer and it gave me what I needed - can't see any faults so far.

Comment: @ohalvors - as I indicated in my fourth paragraph, the issue now is that the *same* problem is still happening, but now SQL Server doesn't bother telling you - of the multiple matching values for a particular `OrderCopyNo`, one of them is going to be used, but you've no way of knowing which one. This e.g. means that if you run the query twice, in theory the results could be different.